# Panel Data Regression in R with Dummy Variables

Tags: r, regression, interaction, panel-data, categorical-encoding

I am currently working on my thesis and thereby analyzing the effects of the increase of COVID-19 cases on the main stock indices of the G7 countries. For this purpose, I have divided the whole period (January 2nd - June 30th) into 4 smaller sub-periods and named them. I.e. the first sub-period was given the name "Incubation".

My problem is that I obviously have panel data. I tried to analyze the stock indices movements in the incubation period by using dummy variables. I.e. I created a dummy, which equals to 1 if the sub-period is equal to incubation and zero otherwise. I want to also include an interaction variable between the COVID-19 cases increase variable and the dummy variable regarding the sub-period.
For this purpose, I used the `plm` function (of package `plm`) with fixed effects (i.e. "within").

However, I cannot achieve any proper result, since there is an error which I really do not understand.

The codes and error are provided below.

```
library(plm)
pd.data <- pdata.frame(rdata, index = c("country","date"))
formula.plm <- pd.data$return ~ pd.data$cases_inc
pd.data <- dummy_cols(pd.data, select_columns = 'sp')
final <- na.omit(pd.data)
reg_incu <- final$return ~ final$cases_inc + final$sp_Incubation 
within_incu <- plm(reg_incu, data=final, model="within", effect="twoways")
```

The error I receive is as follows:

```
Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data,  : 
invalid type (NULL) for variable 'final$cases_incu'
In addition: Warning message:
In pdata.frame(data, index) :
duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
to find out which, use e.g. table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

Comment: Hi Rachel, did you do as the warming suggests and look at `table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")` to find out what the duplicte couples are?